# Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()) doesn't compile although Long is inferred

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream

I cannot compile the following piece of code (try at [**onlinegdb**](https://onlinegdb.com/rJ-nKm3zD)):

```
List<Container<Dto>> list = Arrays.asList(
                new Container<>(new Dto("A"), 10L),
                new Container<>(new Dto("A"), 30L),
                new Container<>(new Dto("B"), 30L));

Map<String, Optional<Long>> mapWrong = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        c -> c.getOutput().getType(),
        Collectors.mapping(
            Container::getDifference, 
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))));     // DOESN'T WORK WITH THIS
```

> incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U,A,R,capture#2 of ?,T,T
> (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
> method getDifference in class Container cannot be applied to given types
> required: no arguments
> found: java.lang.Object
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

I have no idea what causes the compilation error. The `Collectors.mapping` maps an object to a new value and since **`Container::getDifference`** returns **`long`** and the very same type should be inferred into `Collectors.maxBy` and the code should get compiled.

Surprisingly, when I replace the `Comparator.naturalOrder()` with `Comparator.comparingLong(l -> l)`, then it works.

```
Map<String, Optional<Long>> mapCorrect = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        c -> c.getOutput().getType(),
        Collectors.mapping(
            Container::getDifference, 
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingLong(l -> l)))));   // A CHANGE TO FIX IT
```

The objects used (including all-args constructor and getters):

```
public class Container<T> {
    T output;
    long difference;
}
```

```
public class Dto {
    String type;
}
```

Note this is reproducible using OpenJDK both `jdk-11.0.5` and `jdk1.8.0_212`. I use IntelliJ Idea and the IDE doesn't highligh such error, however raises it on compilation.

Comment: Helping the compiler works `Map<String, Optional<Long>> mapWrong = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        c -> c.getOutput().getType(),
                        Collectors.mapping(Container::getDifference,
                                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.<Long>naturalOrder()))))` and this is not Java-11 specific, its same with Java-8 as well.

Comment: @Naman: Nice point! It indeed helps, although the IDE suggests to remove it ("`Explicit type arguments can be inferred`").

Comment: A downvote reason? Is the question unclear or not relevant? Help me to improve it.

Comment: The comment notified me and since I didn't vote I would normalize it. The question could be extended to the IDE support as well, which doesn't complain of compiler error and considers the hint redundant.

Comment: @Naman: Thanks for the comment. I will include that infromation. You are right this might be an issue.

Comment: But do you really want an optional in the result map? Not just `Map<String, Long> map = list.stream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getOutput().getType(), Container::getDifference, Math::max));`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inference engine of the standard Oracle / OpenJDK compiler, versions 8 to 14, cannot correctly track what is going on.

However, Eclipse's compiler can, which is why others say they cannot reproduce the issue.

You need to help it along by specifying:

```java
Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.<Long>naturalOrder()))));     // THIS NOW WORKS
```

Comment: Huh. The first time that ecj was the one that _could_ figure out the type inference.